# My application runs fine on emulator 2.1/2.2 but not on a 2.2 device

Tags: android, build, sdk, screen

Ive written an app and had the build target set as Gingerbread. Ive followed the beginning android games book and so the opengles ive used is v1.0. Ive not written any specific features that need v2.3 or up. The min sdk is v7 and the target is 10. THe app runs perfectly on my gingerbread phone and ICS tablet. It runs fine on the 2.1 and 2.2 emulator. But on on a 2.2 device(a motorola). THe app installs fine but hangs on a white screen?
Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: First step. What does logcat say?

Comment: how do i find out what logcat says on a device?

Comment: @superflyninja ... also "white" is a UI automation framework, edit your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I thought i had my texture dimensions at power of two values. But I didnt. Rescaled and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Enable USB debugging on your phone then run your app on your phone instead of the emulator. and see what errors come up on the cat log

Comment: ah ok!! i didnt know you could do that. Ive jsut not needed to troubleshoot a device until now. thanks

Comment: Ok ive run on the phone with usb debugging enabled but no error messages appear on log cat.any ideas? Ive checked and the max texture size im using should be fine for the phone. (xperia x8)

Comment: I found the problem. I thought i had my texture dimensions at power of two values. But I didnt. Rescaled and it works fine

Comment: @superflyninja since you solved your problem, could you post it as an answer so future visitor will find it easily? Afterwards you could accept your own answer ( http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/ ).